# HTML Content to Javascript Code

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I am trying to take the content in a div tag and turn it into Javascript code. The reason for this is to take the div information and convert it into a Highchart data series.

**HTML Content**

```
<div id="data">{name: 'Point 1',x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 1),x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 8),y: 0},{name: 'Point 2',x: Date.UTC(2014, 12, 1),x2: Date.UTC(2014, 12, 8),y: 0},</div>
```

**Javascript/snippet Content**

```js
$(function () {
var newdata = $("#data");

     (function (H) {
        var defaultPlotOptions = H.getOptions().plotOptions,
            columnType = H.seriesTypes.column,
            each = H.each;

        defaultPlotOptions.xrange = H.merge(defaultPlotOptions.column, {});
        H.seriesTypes.xrange = H.extendClass(columnType, {
            type: 'xrange',
            parallelArrays: ['x', 'x2', 'y'],
            requireSorting: false,
            animate: H.seriesTypes.line.prototype.animate,

            /**
             * Borrow the column series metrics, but with swapped axes. This gives free access
             * to features like groupPadding, grouping, pointWidth etc.
             */
            getColumnMetrics: function () {
                var metrics,
                    chart = this.chart;

                function swapAxes() {
                    each(chart.series, function (s) {
                        var xAxis = s.xAxis;
                        s.xAxis = s.yAxis;
                        s.yAxis = xAxis;
                    });
                }

                swapAxes();

                this.yAxis.closestPointRange = 1;
                metrics = columnType.prototype.getColumnMetrics.call(this);

                swapAxes();

                return metrics;
            },
            translate: function () {
                columnType.prototype.translate.apply(this, arguments);
                var series = this,
                    xAxis = series.xAxis,
                    metrics = series.columnMetrics;

                H.each(series.points, function (point) {
                    var barWidth = xAxis.translate(H.pick(point.x2, point.x + (point.len || 0))) - point.plotX;
                    point.shapeArgs = {
                        x: point.plotX,
                        y: point.plotY + metrics.offset,
                        width: barWidth,
                        height: metrics.width
                    };
                    point.tooltipPos[0] += barWidth / 2;
                    point.tooltipPos[1] -= metrics.width / 2;
                });
            }
        });

        /**
         * Max x2 should be considered in xAxis extremes
         */
        H.wrap(H.Axis.prototype, 'getSeriesExtremes', function (proceed) {
            var axis = this,
                dataMax = Number.MIN_VALUE;

            proceed.call(this);
            if (this.isXAxis) {
                each(this.series, function (series) {
                    each(series.x2Data || [], function (val) {
                        if (val > dataMax) {
                            dataMax = val;
                        }
                    });
                });
                if (dataMax > Number.MIN_VALUE) {
                    axis.dataMax = dataMax;
                }
            }
        });
    }(Highcharts));


    // THE CHART
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'xrange'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Highcharts X-range study'
        },
          plotOptions: {
        series: {
            events: {
                mouseOver: function () {
                    var cur = this;
                    Highcharts.each(this.chart.series, function (series) {
                        if (series !== cur) {
                            series.group.animate({
                                opacity: 0.2
                            }, {
                                duration: 150
                            });
                        } else {
                            series.group.animate({
                                opacity: 1
                            }, {
                                duration: 150
                            });
                        }   
                    });
                },
                mouseOut: function () {
                    this.group.animate({
                        opacity: 1
                    }, {
                        duration: 150
                    });
                }   
            }
        }
    },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: '',
            categories: [],
        },
        series: [$(newdata).text()]
        }]

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="data">{name: 'Point 1',x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 1),x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 8),y: 0},{name: 'Point 2',x: Date.UTC(2014, 12, 1),x2: Date.UTC(2014, 12, 8),y: 0},</div>
```

It pulls the content as text and does not create it as code. Can this be done?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to generate a script tag instead of a div for the data, in which can you can just create a JS variable for your data

Comment: You could call JSON.parse to create an object, and may I suggest to use for example this, `<script id="data" type="json-object">...<script>` instead of a div

Answer (score 1):

If all of the contents of the #data element is properly formatted, all you'll actually have to do is grab the inner html of that element and parse it into JSON.

```
// This is the contents of #data as a String
var data_as_a_string = document.getElementById("data").innerHTML;

// And here it is "in javascript" as an Object
var data_as_an_object = JSON.parse( data_as_a_string );
```

Comment: I tried doing this, but I still couldn't get it to load as data. Take a look at this [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/tagriffith/v24Lc5ov/). I am trying to get the "data" from the <span> and pass it into the highchart data series.

Comment: I made three changes to your JS Fiddle. First, you need the string to be properly formatted. As such and array must be surrounded by square brackets ([]). I added them via concatenation where you grab the innerhtml. Second, you need to use JSON.parse, not JSON.stringify (stringify does the exact opposite, and turns an object into a string). Finally put the variable into the proper location for your Highchart. See my updates here: http://jsfiddle.net/v24Lc5ov/2/

Comment: This worked perfectly!!! until I tried to add non data elements into the HTML. (i.e. {1,2,3,4,5} instead of 1,2,3,4,5). Here is a new jsfiddle showing what I was trying to do. http://jsfiddle.net/tagriffith/4dup5fro/

Comment: There were a couple of things wrong here. First, in true JSON format you must wrap the names of every attribute and every string value in double quotes. Second, because what you are writing your object in HTML, methods such as Date.UTC will not run. You can't write JS in HTML directly, they're two different languages -- to remedy this I changed your code to build the data object based on an array instead, take a look. Also, you copied over the square brackets from my previous entry, which were unnecessary. Now the object is right, although the chart is not. http://jsfiddle.net/4dup5fro/1/

Answer (score 0):

you can try eval function

> The eval() function evaluates JavaScript code represented as a string.

```
eval(string)
eval(" var s='hello'; alert(s);");
```

Comment: That is really **dangerous**, and unnecessary as `JSON.parse` works perfect in this case.

Comment: Agree but some browser may not support JSON methods moreover JSON parse also uses eval to execute the code but it verifies the code before execution which is more secure, anyway thanks

Comment: [JSON.parse browser support is almost 100%](http://caniuse.com/#feat=json), well it is 100% as one can use [this library](http://www.json.org/js.html)